# $state.go not changing URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to change state upon clicking search button.

```
$state.go("abc", {});
```

The problem is, state gets changed successfully but browser URL is not getting updated. Upon debugging further, I found that `$stateChangeStart, $stateChangeSuccess and $locationChangeStart` are fired properly but $`locationChangeSuccess` is not getting fired.
In my controller of state `abc`, I have a server side request to get some data.

```
PlaceService.getDetails.query({}, {}).$promise.then(function(result){
    //do something
});
```

Interesting case is, If I comment out this request, URL is getting updated properly. If I allow to send this request to server, URL is not getting updated. Strange behavior but still happening.

Can anyone tell what might be the reason and how to resolve this?

** Updated

Just to give some rough idea, my config function somewhat looks like this.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {
   var abc = {
        name : 'abc',
        url : '/abc',
        views : {
            'container@' : {
                templateUrl : 'javascript/templates/abc.html',
                controller : 'AbcController'
            }
        },
        resolve : {
            loadMyService: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load(
                  {
                    name: 'tablet',
                    files: ['javascript/services/placeService.js']
                  });
                }],
            loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
              return $ocLazyLoad.load(
                {
                  name: 'tablet',
                  files: ['javascript/controllers/abcController.js']
                });
            }]
        }        
    };

    $stateProvider.state(abc);
});
```

Comment: Can you paste your $stateProvide configuration?

Comment: @RenanLopesFerreira Configuration provided in ques.

Comment: He's asking for the code where you actually pass this to the `$stateProvider.state` API

Comment: Also please post your AbcController code... I see you're using the ocLazyLoad library... I wonder if there is something inside that that expects some return value from your controller.

Comment: @jusopi, please, see the update portion in ques.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$state.go("abc");` instead of `$state.go("abc", {});`. When you call `$state.go()` you shoulld specify only the name of the state

Comment: I am actually passing an object/ stateParam as second param. So in real, it's not empty. ---- eg: $state.go("abc", {"someparam": "value"}); Though I tried with not passing any stateParam, the result is the same.